# Build a CDN URL using an S3 asset in CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

How do I compose a CDN URL using an S3 asset using CloudFront?

As I went through a [guide provided by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/), I wasn't clear to me how the final URL should be composed using the CloudFront's origin or domain, and the path to the S3 asset within the S3 bucket that the CloudFront distribution points to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CloudFront distribution's **Alternative Domain Name** and the **path to the asset** in the S3 bucket.

```
[Alternative Domain Name]/[path to the asset]
```

So for example, if the **Alternative Domain Name** is:

```
my-assets.my-domain.com
```

And the **path to the asset** in the referenced S3 bucket is:

```
some-directory/some-static-files/my-image.jpg
```

The CDN URL would be:

```
https://my-assets.my-domain.com/some-directory/some-static-files/my-image.jpg
```